# Location of user data for Plants vs Zombies?

Tags: macos, plants-vs-zombies

Where is user data stored for Plants vs Zombies on Mac OS X?

I want to play a fresh game, but I also want to be able to go back as needed.

Answer (score 4):

The [FAQ on Popcap's site](http://www.popcap.com/help6.php) lists the location for Popcap games save files on the Mac:

> **Mac**
>
> Below is the location of your game's
>   save file:
>
> ```
> Your User Name/Library/Application Support/PopCap/Game Name
> ```

Though they later state that some of their games store their data at a different location. [This thread](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/strategy/plantsvszombies/answers.html?qid=104244), however, further supports the above path by indicating the path to be:

> /Users/*username*/Library/Application
>   Support/Popcap/PlantsVsZombiesMac/userdata/

Be aware that if you are playing the game through Steam your save files are stored on the Steam cloud as well, so if you change your local copy manually it will create a conflict between the two versions and the game/Steam will ask you to resolve it.

Finally, I'll mention that starting from scratch is also possible by simply creating a new profile in-game. Simply click the sign that says "If this is not you, click here" on the top left of the game's menu as seen here:

[image: PvZ main menu]